# Many a teacher and many a student has/have

Tags: subject-verb-agreement, compound-subjects

> 1. Many a teacher and many a student **has** attended the lecture.
> 2. Many a teacher and many a student **have** attended the lecture.

Which one is correct? And why?

Answer (score 1):

Since in the sentence "Many a teacher has attended the lecture" the verb takes the singular form (please see [here](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/many?q=many), meaning 3) it would be reasonable to assume that your latter sentence is correct because there are homogeneous subjects connected with the conjunction "and".

Perhaps, someone will correct me.

Answer (score 1):

> **Many a teacher is singular**(syntactically)
>
> **Many a student is singular**
>
> **Many a teacher and many a student  are  plural.**( syntactically)

Many a student means many students semantically though.

So I think:

> **Many a teacher and many a student have attended the lecture** is correct.

Answer (score -1):

First one is correct.
Basically it means "**Many** **times**" a teacher and many a student **has** attended the lecture.

Answer (score -3):

Both are incorrect

Many teachers and students have attended the lecture.

Because for one / Singular  Subject we use has.
He, She, it
and for two / plural subject we use has.
They, We

In your example teachers , students and that too many so it should be have attended lectures.

Comment: Both can't incorrect

Comment: Because they are in the test for gifted students

Comment: I am sure who drafted the test paper is not competent.